# Change shell to git bash.exe in windows docker container

Tags: windows, bash, git, docker, shell

I want to change the shell to `bash.exe`from git-for-windows:

I have the docker file:

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809

# $ProgressPreference: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2138#issuecomment-251261324
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
RUN choco install -y git

RUN & 'C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe' -c "ls -al"  #### << Passes
SHELL ["\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bash.exe\"", "-c"] #### << Passes
RUN ls -al                                           #### << Crashes
```

Results in the third statement:
`/usr/bin/bash: Files/Git/bin/sh.exe: No such file or directory`

When I try to quote like the following

```sh
SHELL ["\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bash.exe\"", "-c"]
RUN ls -al
```

the build works, but I dont see any output from `ls -al` and I dont know if it really works?

How can I use `bash.exe` successfully? I am using docker for windows through WSL2 engine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue using base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004.
I am not very familiar with windows command prompt or powershell.

After you install git with chocolatey, update the system PATH environment variable. I used cmd for this because it was the first way I found on stack overflow and it has worked.
I have not tested the run command with a path containing a space so the below command might not work out of the box for you.

```
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN setx path "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin;%path%"
```

With the system path environment variable updated, bash.exe is available at the command line.

```
SHELL ["bash.exe", "-c"]

RUN "ls -la"

ENTRYPOINT ["bash.exe"]
```